# open cart fatal error Cannot redeclare ModelSaleCustomer::getNewsletterSubscribers()

Tags: php, opencart

When I open backend of opencart it returns

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ModelSaleCustomer::getNewsletterSubscribers() in
>   /home/eshopnsa/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_model_sale_customer.php on line 515

I don't understand this. Please help me.

Comment: I did it **this error beacuse of any previous free version of newsletter by other developer installed on your store...
reason: wither u have a vqmod from that module or done manuall changes in files...

please remove the other vqmod u already had, and just use the mod xml supplied with this mod...or if u did manually changes in past for free newsletter module, replace original files or undo changes by that mod..**

Answer (score 0):

This error beacuse of any previous free version of newsletter by other developer installed on your store... reason: wither u have a vqmod from that module or done manuall changes in files... please remove the other vqmod u already had, and just use the mod xml supplied with this mod...or if u did manually changes in past for free newsletter module, replace original files or undo changes by that mod..